# "Plain Text Document" has changed to "text", "Rich Text Document" to "rich text (RTF)", etc

Tags: macos, finder

Sometime recently some file type names have changed — not the file associations or default application, but the name of the file type itself. "Plain Text Document" has changed to "text", "Rich Text Document" to "rich text (RTF)", etc.

[image: "Incorrect" file type names]

I did a `find /Applications -name \*.plist -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep "rich text (RTF)"` and got hits in:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/CoreServices/MobileCoreTypes.bundle/Info.plist`

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetworkCoreTypes-Info.plist`

which do indeed list a whole whack of lowercase filetype names along with the offending ones.

And `sudo find /Library -name \*.plist -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep "rich text (RTF)"` found (along with a bunch of "Permission denied"s):

`/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/MobileCoreTypes.bundle/Info.plist`

`/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetworkCoreTypes-Info.plist`

Anyway...is anyone else seeing this? And/or see how it can be fixed/restored? Granted it's almost entirely aesthetic. But if aesthetics weren't important to me I wouldn't be using a Mac. :)

Comment: So which Terminal command did you use to change the files from Plain Text to RTF.

Comment: I didn't do anything to them. Those are .txt and .rtf files that previously showed as "Plain Text Document" and "Rich Text Document", respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You must have a different text app associated with .txt files.

The "kind" will depend on the app associated (Open with) with that file type.

If you use the TextEdit, those will change back to Plain Text Document.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, that's not the case, as you can see here: http://imgur.com/NCAS8nV

Comment: That is fine with RTF, how about your problem with the .txt files (Plain text)

Comment: Thank you the suggestion, but perhaps you are misunderstanding.

Normally RTF files appear as "Rich Text Document". Now, as of relatively recently, they are appearing as "rich text (RTF)". And plain text files, which were appearing as "Plain Text Document" are now appearing as simply "text".

Something has overridden the type names as specified in, for example, TextEdit's Info.plist. I'd like to figure out how to un-override it.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding.  Just checked, so what is the date on your TextEdit Info.plist file. I have Feb 2 2014.

Comment: Yeah, mine was 2014, too. I touched it, though, as well as the localized .plist in Resources/English.lproj in the faint hope that might give it precedence over whatever else was overriding it. For some reason, another setting from somewhere else is somehow taking precedence over what, for instance, TextEdit defines.

Comment: Here for comparison of the info.plist, open it and find the first entry for the Plain Text. It looks like this <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
   <array>
    <string>com.apple.traditional-mac-plain-text</string>
   </array>

Comment: The Info.plist looks fine for TextEdit. That's not the problem. Something else is overriding the textual name of the type(s).

Comment: Back to my original answer, you have a app that does that. Did you try Open with to see what options (apps) does it offers?

Comment: Yes, there is undoubtedly an application that is doing this. But no, as you originally suggested, it's not due to Open With settings. Note that changing Open With will not change the file *type* as specified by a CFBundleTypeName (as per TextEdit's .plist) or a UTTypeDescription (as per the other .plists noted above). I'm not enough of an expert to say why or even if what's happening is that the UTTypeDescription is overriding the CFBundleTypeName; the UTTypeDescription instances are the only places I can actually find "rich text (RTF)" occurring.

Comment: Actually on my 10.9.5 if I change the Open with to something significantly different than TextEdit in the Get Info the "kind" changes in Finder. I tried open with Console and the result is NSStringPboardType for what it used to be Plain Text kind.

Comment: Ah, so that perhaps confirms my suspicion that something is overriding it, because when I change the Open With application, the "kind" doesn't change. It stays "text" (or "rich text (RTF)").